# Spring boot integration url pagination solution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I using spring (boot) integration in order to connect to a restful WebService and retrieve data from that, Here are some part of my codes:

```
@Bean
public PollerMetadata downloadTrigger()
{
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(config.getDownloadInterval());
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(trigger);
    pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
    return pollerMetadata;
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller()
{
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(10);
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(trigger);
    return pollerMetadata;
}

@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel1", poller = @Poller("downloadTrigger"))
public ResponseEntity<AppsItem[]> download()
{
    String url = "https://example.com/?page{pageNumber}";
    try
    {
        SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());


    ResponseEntity<AppsItem[]> responseEntity = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, AppsItem[].class, 10, 1);


    return responseEntity;
}

@Splitter(inputChannel = "channel1", outputChannel = "channel2")
public List<AppsItem> scrape(ResponseEntity<AppsItem[]> payload)
{

    //do something;
}
```

As you can see, I have a url that accept a variable with pageNum name, i want to increase page number while the response body be empty, I don't know how can i implement it with spring integration.But let me explain what it need:

```
1 - Poller calling inbound method once peer hour
2 - Inbound method start calling WebService from page 1 to page n.
3 - Inbound method should pass data to next channel before fetching next page
```

I need something like below:

```
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel1", poller = @Poller("downloadTrigger"))
public ResponseEntity<AppsItem[]> download()
{
    String url = "https://example.com/?page{pageNumber}";
    try
    {
        SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());


    ResponseEntity<AppsItem[]> responseEntity;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            i++;
            responseEntity = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, AppsItem[].class, 10, i);
            scraper.parse(responseEntity);
            LOG.info("entry={}", "");
            //Send response to the next channel in this loop 
        }
        while (responseEntity.hasBody());


    return responseEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1)` from `downloadTrigger` and the poller (on each poll) will keep calling the `download()` until it returns `null`.

Increment the page count on each call and reset it when no more pages exist; the poller will next run after the interval.

Comment: Can you please post some codes?
I am beginner in spring boot

Comment: i have not any receive method.

Comment: Sorry. I meant download. Internally there's a receive method that calls yours.

Comment: You saved my life bro